# Mathematica "Insert" not working

Tags: insert

Why doesn't this work:

```
mergeList[a_, b_] := (
  list = a;
  Insert[list, 98, 3];
  Do[
   Do[
    (
     If[
      b[[f]] < list[[s]],
      (Insert[list, b[[f]], s]; Break[])
      ]
     ),
    {s, Length[list]}
    ],
   {f, Length[b]}
   ];
  list
  )
```

It doesn't give an error, it just outputs the original value of list = a

For example:

```
mergeList[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4, 5}]
```

outputs `{1, 2, 3, 4}`, and I don't know why.

Comment: `list = Insert[list, b[[f]], s]`

Comment: wow... I was thinking it would manipulate the list variable automatically. Thanks

Comment: A common error. Mathematica functions almost never change things given as arguments (they're 'unmutable'). Some notable exceptions are `Set`, `AppendTo` and `PrependTo`, `Increment` and `AddTo`. You can think of it as working on a copy. If you want the result to overwrite the original you have to use `Set`.

Comment: More specifically, [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19804/12).

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Should I remove this question? It was answered only in the comments, and its sort of a duplicate.